# JavaScript Scripts in dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem. I have a web-app with dynamic content (so URL in browser is always /index.php). I want to add some scripts in that, but they talk about elements that WILL BE created, for example some divs. FireBug throws me an error that element, e.g. $('#div1") is null. When I attach those scripts in loaded views, they're not working because thay need to get document.ready event. How to make those scripts fired?

Comment: show some code, or anything specific which would help others understand what you're doing

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){//shorthand for document.ready
  $('#div1').on("click",function(){
     //do something
  });
});
```

does not work for you ? If you are using a lower jQuery version 1.7- use `.bind()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: What's wrong with `$(...).click(function(){...})` ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
                    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
                    $j(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#calendar").on('click',function(){alert('OK!');});
                        
                });
                </script>`

Comment: because when elements are not available at the document ready, and you try to add an event listener for them, the element can't be found and .click does not work for that.

Comment: The problem is that NONE of scripts won't fire. I also must add I also use mootools here, so I wrote "noConflict" method.

Comment: @kubuscmg could you add the code to the question please.

Comment: @kubuscmg. please read in `on` docs the part about _"delegate events"_

Answer (score 1):

How are you binding your event handlers? In case you are with jQuery 1.7+ you should be using `.on('event',handler)` which should be working on dynamically added elements (i.e. stuff that isn't present on `$(document).ready`)as well.

Earlier versions of jQuery supply the same functionality by using `.live('event',handler);`

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/live/

EDIT: As @gdoron added, jQuery 1.4.2 also added the possibility to use `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ - Yet, as with `.live()` it should be considered deprecated with jQuery 1.7+

Comment: there was the `delegate` function between `on` and `live`! `live` isn't the guy since `Version 1.4.4`!

Comment: @gdoron: Good point, I'll add this. Never really used delegate though...